# Offset in pixels observed in outputted raster when "Clip raster by mask layer" of QGIS is used

Tags: qgis, clip, qgis-processing

I am using QGIS tool "Clip raster by mask layer" in Processing Toolbox for clipping satellite(georeferenced) image raster using shape polygon with "clip to mask layer's extent" setting switched on.

**I observed that the output clipped raster's pixels have an offset of around 0.5 pixel size with respect to source image.**

*Apparently there is a mistake in the algorithm of this tool especially while setting the Geotransform (which decides the positioning) of the output clipped raster.*

How can I access the algorithm of this tool?

EDIT:

Found that the pycode [ClipByMask.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/ClipByMask.py) is apparently (correct me if needed) not the code I am looking for, since it returns argument that calls other GDAL code. Below is the line that shows it:

> return ['gdalwarp', GdalUtils.escapeAndJoin(arguments)]

Also observed that the pycode ClipByMask.py has following imports:

> from processing.algs.gdal.GdalAlgorithm import GdalAlgorithm
>
> from processing.algs.gdal.GdalUtils import GdalUtils

I was looking for the lines which contain geotransform[0] and geotransform[3] which define the positioning of the image top-left corner, but only found:

> ```
>       arguments.append(unicode(geoTransform[1]))
>       arguments.append(unicode(geoTransform[5]))
> ```

above lines are [related to only pixel width and height](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_datamodel.html).

*I am in search of the GDAL code that has code snippets that involve positioning the raster and has functions to do the raster clipping operation.*

Answer (score 5):

- If you installed QGIS using the **OSGeo4W Network Installer**:

  ```
  C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/ClipByMask.py
  ```

---

- If you installed QGIS using the **Standalone Installer** (e.g. QGIS 2.18):

  ```
  C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18/apps/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/ClipByMask.py
  ```

Comment: Thank you. After reading the pyscript of "ClipByMask.py", I realize that it deals only with creating the argument which is in the format required to be given as input to some other GDAL algorithm. I couldn't trace the source GDAL algorithm that actually contains the code snippets to clip the raster. I am editing the question accordingly..

Comment: @SaiKrishna - Apologies, hopefully others can advise on where that _hidden_ code is =)

Comment: _Looking forward!_

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is still present. To correct it, I use the script here => https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80774/translating-reposition-tiff-raster-layer-in-qgis given by maria

Comment: I have the same problem with this tool, but only when the *Keep resolution of input raster* option is selected.  I've submitted a bug report at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/50801