# Recenter maps to overlap in GDAL

Tags: qgis, shapefile, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have a really basic question which I can't wrap my head around.

I have a GeoTIFF of the world and a shapefile containing the oceans. The problem is that the GeoTIFF is centered at -180° longitude while the shapefile is centered at 0° longitude.

Looking at their SRS info using `gdalsrsinfo` it looks like they use exactly the same basic WGS84 projection.

How can I get them to overlap?

[image]

Comment: The GeoTIFF seems centered at +180 longitude (instead of -180), its coordinates seems to go from 0 to +360.

Comment: Please decide whether you wish to ask about QGIS or GDAL in this particular question. You can always ask about the other in a separate question.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't know this is a problem. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca so it's a coordinates issue and not a projection issue? Is there a gdal command to fix that?

Comment: @Flavio, The shapes overlaps, therefore seems to be well projected. I don't know if can be fixed with one command. But _"copy the raster with a -360 shift in x coordinate, merge both rasters and clip within the extents"_ process, should be posible.

Comment: Thanks for your input @GabrielDeLuca. It brought me to this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80774/how-to-translate-reposition-a-tif-raster-layer which helped me solve the issue.

Comment: @PolyGeo I edited the original question to be more focused. How can I reopen the question to post my solution?