# Is it possible to apply affine transformation (translation) to raster image?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, translation, affine-transformation

Is it possible to move/translate a raster image in QGIS 2.2 (without using georeferencer) just like it can be done with a shapefile ? If not, alternatively can this be done with ArcGis?

Comment: you can with the georeferencing tool in ArcGIS (there are manual translation, rotation and scale tools without GCP's)

Comment: ok great many thanks i hope there is a simple way of doing it in QGIS as well. Is it possible easily batch process in ArcGIS (using model builder maybe)?

Comment: if you need to batch, then it is not manual translation anymore. I would directly change the world file or use gdal and python to modify the origin of the iamge coordinate. What you need seems to be answered here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13561/how-to-translate-reposition-a-raster-in-python?rq=1

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS desktop and QGIS you wish to ask about in this question.  Otherwise you are effectively asking two questions which goes against the [Tour].