# Looking for QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS "Shift" tool

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff

I'm looking for a tool or a plug-in for QGIS that would allow me to shift rasters to new coordinates. An equivalent of ["Shift"](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Shift/00170000007t000000/) tool in ArcGIS would be the best option.

I know I can edit the world file that comes along with the raster to do this, but some raster formats (like GeoTIFF) contain their metadata inside their binary format.

Comment: A python solution can be found here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80774/how-to-translate-reposition-a-tif-raster-layer and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13561/how-to-translate-reposition-a-raster-in-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just used this in R and it solved the problem.

Page 195 from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf (use table of contents for quick access)

```
r <- raster()
r <- shift(r, dx=1, dy=-1)
```

Edit 1: Updated the link

Edit 2: Updated for package changes in 2.9-22 (https://github.com/rspatial/raster/issues/66)

Comment: Link is broken - please update

Comment: Updated from official R docs. (Glad it's still being used!)

Comment: That's nice but it is not QGIS as the asker specified?

Comment: ...you know, you're right haha. Forgive my internship-era answer! But yeah It did help me before, so I just put it in.

Answer (score 10):

The `Rasmover` plugin should do what you want.

You have to allow for experimental plugins to get it in the plugin list.

The result is a virtual raster file, which you can edit with a text editor to adjust the parameters if needed.

Comment: Thanks, it's not exactly what I had in mind, but this actually works. You can later save the edited vrt as a normal, standalone raster. I wish this plugin had a dialog window where you could input new coordinates.

Answer (score 7):

For this job I am satisfied with **QGIS plugin** [Freehand Raster Georeferencer](http://gvellut.github.io/FreehandRasterGeoreferencer/). Allows these simple operations in an user friendly GUI: Move, Rotate, Scale, Adjust sides, 2 Points referencer.

Final export consists of three files: TIF, WorldFile (.tfw) and additional information (e.g. projection, etc.) into auxiliary file (.aux.xml).

I usually merge three files into a GeoTIFF e.g. with GDAL. I also strongly recommend to apply some compression method (the result from the Plugin is uncompressed), e.g.

`gdal_translate -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE input.tif output.tif`

Comment: The plugin is not outputing a tif file. Only tfw.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the already existing answers, it can be done with `gdal_translate`, using the command line option `a_ullr` [(see documentation)](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-a_ullr).

With `a_ullr` you can specify the new upper-left and lower-right coordinates of the raster, so for example if the raster extent as seen in "Properties" is "`100,400:300,200`", then to shift by +1 unit in x and +2 units in y the command becomes:

```
gdal_translate -a_ullr 101 402 301 202 input.tif output.tif
```

`gdal_translate` can be accessed from the QGIS processing pane and "-a_ullr 101 402 301 202" can be input under "Additional command line arguments".

The method was previously described in ["Applying a simple X,Y shift or translation to a raster GeoTIFF file using GDAL "](https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2017/07/applying-simple-xy-shift-or-translation.html).