# Fixing digitized map using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I have some cartographic maps I need to fix the position/digitizing.

If you look on the below image you will see that the point layer is not exactly at the center of the map. The exact center is represented by the point shapefile.

Both map and point shapefile are on the same SRC (WGS 84)

[image]

The problem is on the map precision.

Is there any way I can easily "drag" the map to center it on the orientation point?

I know I can digitize it again in order to fix the map position, but since I have more than 100 maps with this problem, I am looking for an easier and faster way to it on QGIS?

Comment: A: what is the measurement of the offset, and B: is the offset amount consistent across maps?

Comment: I have a representation of 55km from upper left corner to upper right corner and 55km from top to bottom, but offset is not consistent. The problem is that the maps were manually digitized one by one and the differences shown above (map and center point shape) is different on each map.

Comment: If you also want to ask about ArcGIS Desktop then just do it in a separate question so that you can describe what precisely you have already tried with that.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/131761/113585) help any? I don't know that there's a quicker way for this sort of thing.

Comment: @JoshC. On link you provided there is a reference to "rasmover" plugin. It's experimental but it's faster then digitizing everything again. Thanks