# Move TIFF in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, translation

I've got a TIFF imported as raster in my QGIS with KBS WGS84. Now I duplicate the layer and want to move that raster to the right edge of the first TIFF. So I just want to move / translate the TIFF to the right. Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: check out this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131761/how-to-shift-a-raster-in-qgis