# Move Landsat 7 Image in Grass 7

Tags: grass-gis, landsat

I got 2 landsat 7 images from the same place but different date of adquisition, image A is well placed, but image B is shifted about 1500 meters east and 14700 meters north. I need to use both images to correct stripping issues, because of that both need to be aligned. How can i correct image B to be aligned with image A in grass 7?

Comment: Are the images the originals, in the original UTM projection? Are they the same path and row?

Comment: Yes, they are originals, UTM wgs84 zone 19 and the same path and row, 1-75

Comment: I must say, I have never heard of Landsat image bands not aligning. It might be worthwhile to download the same Path/Row for some other date, and compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13561/how-to-translate-reposition-a-raster-in-python) i was able to shift a raster using the python console on grass.